# cant show updated state (REACT-NATIVE)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to show updated state name in the sidedrawer of my app,my functions work fine as I can see the name PRINTED twice in the console but for some reason I cannot show the name value on the app screen(shows starting value ""),I am thinking i might be using the wrong lifecycle method can someone help me?

```
state = {
    name: {
        value: ""
    }

componentWillMount() {

getTokens((value) => {
        if (value[0][1] === null) {
            alert('whoops')
        } else {
            this.props.UpdateUserData(value[0][1]).then(()=>{
                console.log(this.props.User.userData)
            this.state.name.value = this.props.User.userData
            console.log(this.state.name.value)
            })
}
    })
}
 render() {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.displayname}>{this.state.name.value} 
                 </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: you must use this.setState(); to update component state and force a rerender

Comment: Do not use componentWillMount for long running and network calls. Use componentDidMount instead. Use Promises/thunks. Also check your arrow functions: the usual syntax goes like this: nameOfFunction = (paramOne, paramTwo) => {....}

Comment: You are mutating the state directly. Always use the setState method to modify the state values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.name.value = this.props.User.userData`

Do not mutate your state directly because it won't rerender component, instead using `setState` method as below

`this.setState({
      name: this.props.User.userData
    });`

Comment: @sod.heretic: Do mark it as answer as a reference for others who are facing similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quote from [react-bits](https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html)

> Avoid async initialization in componentWillMount()
>
> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-render. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method.

Replace `componentWillMount` with `componentDidMount`. Should work

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated. Always use `componentDidMount`.

Comment: componentdidmount made no difference it still showed nothing, setting state with this.setState solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.state.name.value` which is not correct. It sets the state but doesn't actually cause the component to re-render itself. Instead, you need to use the setState method to change the value of a state. This will make a call to re-render the component after the state has been changed. 
The example of that approach would be

`this.setState({
      name: this.propos.User.userData
               });`

Although this approach works but it's not advised to mutate the value of state. States need to be considered immutable according to the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount does not differ much from constructor - it is also called once only in the initial mounting life-cycle. Many will be tempted to use this function in order to send a request to fetch data and expect the data to be available before the initial render is ready. This is not the case — while the request will be initialized before the render, it will not be able to finish before the render is called.

this.setState can solve the issue in this case.